# What is the name for the parts of a number in a given base?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

What is the name for the parts of a number in a given base.

For example:

```
1000
^^^^
||||
|||- The "ones"
||- The "twos"
|- The "fours"
-The "eights"
```

Comment: I think you would call those the "digits".

Comment: @Nilknarf: digits is a general term and does not allow you to specify particular weights.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific terminology for other bases. I would use the rank-0, rank-1, rank-2... digits. Alternatively, first position, second position, third position... (digits), though there is an ambiguity about where position 1 is. And though this is not elegant, you can explicit the values with weight-1, weight-2, weight-4... bits.

Comment: The ones place, the b's place, the b squares place, the b cubes place. Or I think the  the n-th powers position, should be clear to anyone in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to Nilknarf's answer that the individual numerals are digits, we should discuss face value and place value. In $24$, $2$ has face value $2$ and place value $20$.

Digits are sometimes described in terms of the base in which they are used, e.g. decimal (base-10) digits or binary digits (bits for short; base-2).

Comment: But the question asked, then, is what do you call the position of the digit n that has a face value of $n*b^k$ to specify that it represents k'th power position?  This post, while clear and succinct and useful, doesn't address that specific question.

Comment: @fleablood I can't see where that question is asked, but I'll address it now. Going back to the example of $24$ in base ten, the $2$ is called the tens digit. Similarly, the $2$ in $241$ in octal (base 8) is the sixty-fours digit.